# Creating a string from a path

Tags: cypher

I have a chain of nodes, e.g.

```
{Name: 'X'}->{Name: 'Y'}->{Name: 'Z'}
```

and I'd like to create a string representing the path in cypher (I know I can do it client-side but I want to do it in a query) that would look like this:

```
'X->Y->Z'
```

is that feasible? I've investigated use of collect() and UNWIND, and have googled till I'm blue in the face

thoughts?

*** Edit I ***

as an addendum (and to make the problem more difficult) my query is going to return a collection of paths (a tree, a DAG), so I'll need to create a string for each of the paths in the tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REDUCE is your friend here:

```
WITH reduce(s="",n in nodes(p) | s+n.name+"->") as str 
RETURN substring(str,0,length(str)-2)
```

or if you want to save the extra operation

```
RETURN reduce(s=head(nodes(p)).name, n in tail(nodes(p)) | s+"->"+n.name)
```

or with APOC

```
RETURN apoc.text.join([n in nodes(p) | n.name],"->")
```

Comment: what is APOC?? is that a 3.0+ thing?

Comment: @ekkis APOC is a drop-in library that consists of ~300 procedures, helpers for many types of tasks, you can find it here: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_introduction

Answer (score 1):

found an old posting (2014) from Michael Hunger with the answer:

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/147ch1nj9b/concatenate-nodes-properties